# I need to reset Liquibase in my project. How can I do that?

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-hibernate, liquibase-sql

I have a SpringBoot project with a lot of entities, we are using liquibase since always, but know my TL had the idea of reset all the migrations and run the liquibase like a restart of the project to generate a big migration with all the informations of the entities in database in a single file. How can I do that? Is it possible?

Observation: I'm going to delete all the other migrations, so basically is like run the liquibase for the first time, but in this case liquibase is already tracking the history.

I tried to delete all the olg migration and use the update command to generate a new file, but I got a error.

Comment: Have you checked out this post from Liquibase official docs https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/trimming-changelogs.html